# Java - Regular expression to match strings not containing quote and backslash characters

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

Using Java, I am having some problems in finding a regular expression in order to match any string not containing **"** and **\** characters.

I have tried solving this problem using the following regular expression:

```
[^\\\"]+
```

That did not work, so I have tried with the following one: `[^(\\\")]+`, but this did not solve my problem too.

Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `s.matches("[^\\\\\"]+")`. The linked answer dwells upon how to escape the two chars correctly.

Comment: That worked good! Thank you really.